# Capybara's save_and_open_page with absolute paths for stylesheets and javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm using **rspec** features with **capybara** for testing my **rails 3.1** application. Sometimes it's useful to save the static html of a page we're breaking on and have a glance on it. That what the **save_and_open_page** method is for.

But capybara generates an html file in a directory called **tmp/capybara**, so if my paths for stylesheets and javascripts look like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1362462583" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

they won't be found, because this absolute path assumes we're in a **/public** directory.

What is the best solution to save a page and open it properly?

Answer (score 4):

Asset pipeline support for `save_and_open_page` will be available in Capybara v2.1, see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/958

In the meantime you have to use the selenium driver and halt the test execution using methods `sleep` `gets` or `binding.pry` so that you can interact with the selenium browser